# How do I recover from boot error when my root is on RAID and LVM?

Tags: lvm, boot, software-raid, arch-linux

When a (Archlinux) system that has its root on RAID and LVM is misconfigured and does not boot, what steps are needed to recover it?

Comment: Anyone can make a mistake but to make the same mistake three times takes an incredible amount of carelessness.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers  ...or a lot of hard work and careful planning.  The real trick is making it look like a different mistake, and someone else's fault so you can bill for all the extra hours, though.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers my apologies, I had misunderstood that this site is for people running servers, while it is for people running sites in a /professional/ setting. I am very careless with this server, and I should've posted my question on Linux&Unix instead of here :) Not sure why it's not a real question though. I still think it is useful information, even if it happens just once instead of three times.

Comment: @Tinco, I suggest investing in a UPS to help eliminate this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get a linux live usb stick, I use the debian one and boot from it.

If your server is under a staircase or some other hard to sit location do the following three steps:

1 Become root, type `adduser myname` and enter your login information.

2 Add the line `myname ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `/etc/sudoers`.

3 Type `sshd` to start the sshd daemon if it is not already running (it is on the debian stick).

Now I assume you are logged into your machine. Type `sudo -s` to become root.

To find your raid arrays and mount them perform the following two steps:

1 Type `mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` to setup the configuration.

2 Type `madam --assemble --scan` to ready the devices.

Now to mount your LVM partitions do the following steps:

1 Type `lvscan` to find all your volumes.

2 Type `vgchange -ay dirname` where dirname is the directory of your volume groups. (for me `/dev/data` and `/dev/array` because lvscan shows `/dev/data/home` and `/dev/array/root`)

3 For each volume you can now make a directory in `/mnt` and mount the partition there by typing `mount /dev/array/root /mnt/root` when root is the name of the partition you want to mount and `/dev/array/root` the volume it is in.

Now type `mkdir /mnt/boot` and mount your boot partition there if you have your boot directory on a separate partition I have mine on a raid device too so I type `mount /dev/md1 /mnt/root/boot`.

Now we have all filesystems setup, it's time to chroot into our broken system. First change into your root directory like so `cd /mnt/root`. Then perform the following series of commands:

```
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount -t sysfs sys sys/
mount -o bind /dev dev/
mount -t devpts pts dev/pts/
```

Now it's time for the main event, type `chroot . /bin/bash` and you are back into your old system. You can repair it like normal, perhaps run `pacman -Syu` to install all updates, and don't forget to run `mkinitcpio` if your kernel changes!